# Maximum R2 of predictions based on correlation

Tags: r, machine-learning, predictive-models

Is there a way that one can tell the maximum R2 or prediction algorithms can be achieved depending on the correlations between variables or using another way? And does this have to do with Rademacher Complexity?

The problem that I am facing that I have achieved a specific R2 score and someone has to told me that you cannot go beyond that it is even proved from the correlation.

Comment: You might be able to do something like this if you make the assumption that your predictor variables are completely orthogonal, but that's almost never an assumption that will hold

Comment: So it is impossible to do so.

Comment: Left a quick comment and not an answer since I haven't given a great deal of thought to it - I could be wrong. I would reserve judgement till you get some more carefully thought-through responses.

Comment: It depends on whether the set of regressors is fixed (e.g. by theory or some study design) or not. In the latter case you are always able to create new regressors (e.g. interactions) until R-squared is 1.